# Слияние вложенных в списки словарей

Tags: python, list, список, словари, слияние

Имею 2 списка с вложенными словарями вида:
Список1

```
[{'id': 'RU041', 'voltage': 24.3, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 22:58:05', 'color': 'green'}, {'id': 'RU042', 'voltage': 24.5, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 23:02:33', 'color': 'green'}, {'id': 'RU043', 'voltage': 24.5, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 22:57:21', 'color': 'green'}, {'id': 'RU044', 'voltage': 28.1, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-15 01:30:09', 'color': 'red'}, {'id': 'RU045', 'voltage': 24.7, 'timeTpi': '2017-12-12 17:53:01', 'color': 'red'}, {'id': 'RU047', 'voltage': 24.4, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-03 10:06:23', 'color': 'red'}, {'id': 'RU048', 'voltage': 24.2, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 22:58:57', 'color': 'green'}, {'id': 'RU050', 'voltage': 25.0, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 23:00:00', 'color': 'green'}, {'id': 'RU052', 'voltage': 24.0, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 22:59:54', 'color': 'green'}, {'id': 'RU053', 'voltage': 24.6, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 23:02:53', 'color': 'green'}, {'id': 'RU055', 'voltage': 23.8, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 22:59:48', 'color': 'yellow'}, {'id': 'RU056', 'voltage': 23.8, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-11 14:45:53', 'color': 'red'}, {'id': 'RU057', 'voltage': 24.3, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 23:00:14', 'color': 'green'}, {'id': 'RU058', 'voltage': 23.8, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 22:58:45', 'color': 'yellow'}]
```

Список2

```
[{'id': 'RU001', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU002', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU003', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU004', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU005', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU006', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU007', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU008', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU009', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU010', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU011', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU012', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU013', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU014', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU015', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU016', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU017', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU018', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU019', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU020', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU021', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU022', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU023', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU024', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU025', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU026', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU027', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU028', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU029', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU030', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU031', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU032', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU033', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU034', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU035', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU036', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU037', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU038', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU039', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU040', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU041', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU042', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU043', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU044', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU045', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU046', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU047', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU048', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU049', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU050', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU051', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU052', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU053', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU054', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU055', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU056', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU057', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU058', 'status': 'ONLINE'}, {'id': 'RU059', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'RU099', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}]
```

Необходимо чтобы при объединении к первому списку добавилось из второго только status, при этом ненужные id из второго списка не добавлялись. Очень прошу немного расписать логики, я просто целый день в поисках и голову ломаю как это реализовать.

Comment: имеется в виду, что если id при слиянии совпало, то в данном словаре появился параметр status?

Comment: Да, все верно. получится должно так: [{'id': 'RU041', 'voltage': 24.3, 'timeTpi': '2019-10-27 22:58:05', 'color': 'green', status:'(статус из списка 2 на id RU041)'},]

Answer (score 1):

Например так

```
for elem in l1:
    t=list(filter(lambda l2: l2['id'] == elem['id'], l2))
    elem['status']=t[0]['status']
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, просто пока не было проектов(уроков) не попадалось с lamda, (можете подсказать что она делает в данном случае?, если вас не затруднит конечно).

Comment: Применяется фильтр, который с помощью лямбда функции выбирает те элементы, для которых `l2['id'] == elem['id']` истинно.

Answer (score 1):

возьмем 1 список за х а второй за у, тогда

```py
for i in x:
    id = i['id']
    for j in y:
        if j['id'] == id:
            x[x.index(i)]['status'] = y[y.index(j)]['status']
```

идем по 1 списку: запоминаем айди из каждого словаря, идем по второму списку: если айди 1 и 2 совпали, то в словарь из 1 списка под ключом статус записываем статус из словаря во 2 списке

Comment: Так, если я правильно понял логику вашего кода мы берем элемент 1го (нужного!, короткого) списка и по нему итерацией с if "прогоняем" второй (полный) список. Я честно, не до конца понял как работает конструкция последней строки: x[x.index(i)]... Ну думаю index загуглю и будет уже проще. И второй момент для общего развития, если мне надо будет наоборот из первого во второй добавить(что нибудь), то: у нас получается меняются местами элементы последней строки верно? Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @HuanGi да, все правильно, прогоняем первый список, берем айди из каждого списка, ищем его в каждом из второго списка, если находим - добавляем в 1 список